Bootfehler: Disabling IRQ #9
I hope someone can help. I cannot boot my Ubuntu 20.04 on my Lenovo Ideapad anymore. The error is

acpi_irq


Disabling IRQ #9

Booting via "Extended Options", recovery mode works, but then there is no graphical interface.
Kernelloptions irqpoll und nomodeset do not work.
What I did before the problem occured:

nvtop installed und deinstalled again -> Maybe that did some NVidia things? My Laptop has an Intel-Chip.
geoclue deinstalled -> Is that ok anyway?

Best regards 
Herbert
